# Recording RTSP stream with fragmentation

Tags: rtsp

I have problem with below fragmentation. I don't know how can I do this.
Right now I use:

```
cvlc rtsp://address --sout "#transcode{}:duplicate{dst=std{access=file,mux=ts,dst={/mnt/record/test.h264}}}"
```

I want to fragment this stream every single hour. Like this:
record001
record002
record003

One file should be 1h of stream.

How can I do this?

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to achieve it with vlc but I can show you with ffmpeg:

```
 ffmpeg -analyzeduration 0 -re -i rtsp://address -c:v copy -map 0 \ 
  -f segment -reset_timestamps 0 -segment_time 3600 \
  -movflags faststart stream%d.mp4
```

`sement_time 3600` (3600 secs = 1hour)

`-reset_timestamps 0` and  `-movflags faststart` shift the moov atom to start of each file for streaming playback in web browser if required

`-analyzeduration 0` prevent attempting to find input duration

`-re` tell ffmpeg the input is live